# Cordova net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED after take photo on motorola e7 and android 10

Tags: android, cordova, motorola

Please can you help me, I have a problem with a cordova application, after taking a photo, it does not appear, and only this attachment message remains

[attachment message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU99x.jpg)

and the error appears on the console
[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBm7A.jpg)
net::ERR_ACCES_DENIED

I did a little research, I found the cordova-diagnostic-plugin, but apparently even with the permission, the photos still don't show up
[cordova-plugin-diagnostic console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivexv.jpg)

I'm working on a motorola e7 with android 10.

guys would anyone have any idea what's going on?

Best Regards! and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same error ERR_ACCES_DENIED when I updated my app to sdk 30 and trying to read a file.

I solved adding this lines to function init() in CodovaMainActivity.java

```
protected void init() {
        appView = makeWebView();
        createViews();
        if (!appView.isInitialized()) {
            appView.init(cordovaInterface, pluginEntries, preferences);
        }
        //Added Lines
        WebView webView = (SystemWebView)(appView.getEngine().getView());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        //--------------
        cordovaInterface.onCordovaInit(appView.getPluginManager());

        // Wire the hardware volume controls to control media if desired.
        String volumePref = preferences.getString("DefaultVolumeStream", "");
        if ("media".equals(volumePref.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))) {
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you share the full code of this java file?

Comment: Relative path：platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java